# Invalid reference during callback

Tags: android, callback, java-native-interface, android-2.2-froyo

i have an object that is used for calling callback functions:

```
static jobject o;
```

i have assigned the callback function to that object through a pointer:

```
o=env->NewGlobalRef(callback);
```

The same pointer, `env`, points towards the function `CallVoidMethod` that uses JNI to reach to the java code.

```
env->CallVoidMethod(o, methodId, pDeviceId, deviceStatus, statusReason, connectionProgressInfo);
```

However on calling this function, the system is getting crashed, and VM says that it's an invalid reference to static jobject o and then it crashes.

My code is as follows :

```
static jint android_net_wimax_subscribeDeviceStatusChange(JNIE nv* env, jobject clazz, jobject jdeviceId, jobject callback)
{

//  LOGD(" android_net_wimax_subscribeDeviceStatusChange() ->D1");
o = env->NewGlobalRef(callback);
//o = callback;

//   LOGD(" android_net_wimax_subscribeDeviceStatusChange() ->D2");


return (jint)::SubscribeDeviceStatusChange(deviceId, fun_IndDeviceStatusUpdate);
}

void fun_IndDeviceStatusUpdate(WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pDeviceId, WIMAX_API_DEVICE_STATUS deviceStatus,
WIMAX_API_STATUS_REASON statusReason, WIMAX_API_CONNECTION_PROGRESS_INFO connectionProgressInfo)
{

JNIEnv *env = NULL; 
int nResult = -1; 


//  LOGD(" AttachCurrentThread() ->D1");

nResult = g_jVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

//  LOGD(" AttachCurrentThread() ->D2-%d",nResult);

if ((nResult != 0) || (env == NULL))
{ 
LOGD(" AttachCurrentThread() failed");
} 
else
{
//   LOGD(" AttachCurrentThread() ->D3");


if(o == NULL)
{

LOGD(" o is NULL ");

}
else
{
LOGD(" o is not NULL ");

}

jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(o);

//   LOGD(" AttachCurrentThread() ->D4");
jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(cls, "callback", "(Landroid/net/wimax/structs/DeviceId;III)V");

//  LOGD(" AttachCurrentThread() failed->D5");
if (methodId) {
env->CallVoidMethod(o, methodId, pDeviceId, deviceStatus, statusReason, connectionProgressInfo);
}

if (g_jVM->DetachCurrentThread() != JNI_OK) {
LOGE("%s: DetachCurrentThread() failed", __FUNCTION__);
}
}

//   LOGD("JNI->CALLBACK->D3");

}
```

> <<< D/wimax   ( 1673): before CallVoidMethod() W/dalvikvm( 1673): JNI WARNING: 0x48e31dec is not a valid JNI reference
>
> W/dalvikvm( 1673): in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run ()V (CallVoidMethodV)
>
> I/dalvikvm( 1673): "Thread-55" prio=5 tid=45 RUNNABLE
>
> I/dalvikvm( 1673):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x43b6c930 self=0x306370
>
> I/dalvikvm( 1673):   | sysTid=2000 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=3194272

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

Without code to look at it's hard to say, but I would guess you're trying to use a local reference after the function it was created in has returned to the VM.

You can get some basic advice from the Android "JNI Tips" document in the [Dalvik docs](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/jni-tips.html;hb=HEAD) (see "Local vs. Global References"), and more detailed information from the official JNI documentation.

Comment: hey fadden, i have added code as well. kindly have a look at it.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it.  You talk about creating a global ref to "callback" called "o", but the CallVoidMethod call that is failing doesn't use either of those.  One or more of "pDeviceId", "deviceStatus", "statusReason", or "connectionProgressInfo" is bad.  Add a log message that prints all four as hex ("%p") above the CallVoidMethod and see which one matches up with the value shown in the JNI WARNING line.

Comment: hi fadden, i have added the complete source code, maybe you can have a clear understanding now..

Comment: You have "WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pDeviceId", but you're passing that into the VM as if it were a jobject (first arg to the method is a Landroid/net/wimax/structs/DeviceId;).  Make sure that has the correct type, and that it's a global reference if it's being held natively across calls.

Comment: But what I am getting is that the reference to jobject o at                 "        env->callvoidmethod(o,methodId, pDeviceId, deviceStatus, statusReason, connectionProgressInfo); " 
 
is invalid. What could be the reason behind this? How can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pastebin or the preformatted tag. In fun_IndDeviceStatusUpdate you reference deviceStatusChangeCB but I do not see where it is declared or assigned. You use o as the static global reference to the callback. Shouldn't o be where you look for the class and not deviceStatusChangeCB?

Fadden is also right that the first argument to the java callback method is an instance of class android/net/wimax/structs/DeviceId. Are you sure that WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P is a jobject instance of that class? Are you sure the error message (can you post that?) is referring to o and not to the argument?

Also, are you sure it is safe to detach the JVM from the thread this method is being invoked from (e.g. is this a Java thread)?

Comment: aweisberg, i guess you are right and the error is on the argument only.

i have replaced devicestatusChangeCB with o and have added the error log as well.

what do u suggest for making WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID  a jobject instance of the class?

Comment: am also getting the following error messages -

CALBACK -> ppdeviceId= 0x48e31e38
.
.
.


GetMethodID() ->D5

env=0x2C89b0 deviceStatusChangeCB = 0x43b8de08 methodId = 0x412f6620 pdeviceId = 0x48e31e38 DeviceStatus = 5 statusreason=0, connectionprogressinfo=0

D/Wimax 1673 before CallVoidMethod()

W/dalvikvm  JNI warning: 0x48e31dec is not a valid JNI reference

W/dalvikvm is Ldalvik/system/NativeStart, run() V (CallVoidMethod V)

I/dalvikvm "Thread-55" prio=5 tid=45  Runnable
D/Wimax 1673 before CallVoidMethod()

W/dalvikvm JNI warning: 0x48e31dec is not a valid JNI reference

Comment: I don't know what WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P is or where it came from. Assuming there is some logical mapping from a WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P to a android/net/wimax/structs/DeviceId you can instantiate or retrieve an instance of android/net/wimax/structs/DeviceId that corresponds to the instance of WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P that you have.

You can use NewObject to instantiate the DeviceId and pick the correct constructor or if it is an enum/singleton type thing you can invoke whatever static methods/getters are available to retrieve the correct one.
Also, android/net/wimax/* is not part of the Android API

Comment: WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P has been defined as 

"static WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pdeviceid ", in some other related file. I used the following code for instantiating WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P ---

  jobject NewObjectV (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jmethodID methodId, WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pDeviceId); 

but then i got the following error ---- undefined reference to 'android ::NewObjectV(_JNIEnv *, _jclass *, _jmethod *, _WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P * ).

should I use NewGlobalRef to remove this error ? or is there any other way for referencing ?

Comment: Is that a compiler error? I need to see more code to understand what you are doing. "static WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pdeviceid" is not a definition. It is a declaration of storage for a WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P. Are you sure WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P is a Java object that can be instantiated?

"jobject NewObjectV (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jmethodID methodId, WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pDeviceId);", is that a function prototype?

Comment: Yeah, its a compiler error. "jobject NewObjectV (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jmethodID methodId, WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pDeviceId);"  is not a function prototype. I used this statement to create an object "NewObjectV" and then used it in place of "WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pdeviceId" in void fun_IndDeviceStatusUpdate(WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P pDeviceId, WIMAX_API_DEVICE_STATUS deviceStatus,WIMAX_API_STATUS_REASON statusReason... )
This is when I got the error--undefined reference to 'android ::NewObjectV(_JNIEnv *, _jclass *, _jmethod *, _WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P * )
What should be the code to avoid this?

Comment: I need to see the entire code in http://pastebin.com/ to understand what is going on. That doesn't look like a valid method invocation because it specifies a return type as well as the type of all the arguments (which makes it a function prototype). It doesn't look like you can instantiate WIMAX_API_DEVICE_ID_P as a Java object (using env->NewObject) because it is not a jclass reference.